# How do I create a generic environment template with optional arguments declared inside the environment?

Tags: environments, margins, optional-arguments, marginnote

I am posting this as a general question prior to introducing the specific use case.  Apologies if this has already been posted and I am using the incorrect terms for what I want, my searches have been relatively fruitless.

## General Case

I want to create a generic environment template that is passed commands from inside the environment.  These commands then define how the environment renders on compile.  I want to do this so the number of optional commands I pass to the environment is arbitrary for formatting purposes.  Additionally, I want to add a large number of optional commands while avoiding a giant string of `{}{}{}{}`.

Here is a non-working example of what I want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{testenv}%
    {%
        This is \Alice\Bob
        \begin{center}
        I want to talk about \Bob
    }%
    {%
        \end{center}
    }%

\newcommand{\Alice}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\Bob}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}
    \begin{testenv}
        \Alice{asdf}
        \Bob{jkl}
        this is everything
    \end{testenv}
    
    \begin{testenv}
        \Bob{jkl}
        this is just Bob
    \end{testenv}
\end{document}
```

In this example, the custom environment always prints "I want to talk about \Bob" along with additional text.  However, the header for the `verbatim` environment is dependent on what, if anything, we put in `\Alice` and `\Bob`.

### Relevant Posts

- I know how to make arguments optional using the `ifthen` package as described in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812214/latex-optional-arguments.  I did not include that part in this example for simplicity purposes.
- I know that optional arguments are possible for commands, but I don't know how this works with environments: [Optional arguments in "families"... When and how?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378409/optional-arguments-in-families-when-and-how).

### The Ask

- Obviously this doesn't work.  Am I completely off base when thinking about the relationship between commands and environments in TeX?
- Is there a way to make this general example work?
- Is this a case for `xparse`?  I have never used it, so how would I do this?

## Specific Case

What I really want to do is create a custom recipe environment with relevant information in the margins (this is a niche case, so I figured I would pose the general question first). For this, I am using the `marginnote` package.  There is a lot of information I want to have available to the margin, and I want to do it with variables for ease of replication.  Currently, I have individual commands for different elements I want in the box.  From my style template **(This is not a MWE)**:

```
\newcommand{\serves}[1]{%
    \marginnote{Serves: #1~\\*}%
}
\newcommand{\vegetarian}{%
    \marginnote{\textcolor{forestgreen}{\textbf{Veggie}}}~\\*%
}
\newcommand{\vegan}{%
    \marginnote{\colorbox{green!20}{\textbf{Vegan}}}~\\*%
}
\newcommand{\preptime}[1]{%
    \marginnote{Prep: #1}~\\*%
}
\newcommand{\cooktime}[1]{%
    \marginnote{Cook time: #1}~\\*%
}
```

Individual recipes require specific combinations of these, often multiple.  You will notice the hacky `~\\*` at the end of each command.  If I do not include this, the boxes overlap each other.  If I do include it, the line breaks also persist in the document.  See example image:

[image: A comparison of my example template with and without the ~\\*]

I am converting my hacky solution to a cleaner template that avoids the overlap problem in my ``newenvironment{recipe}, but I am yet to find a way to do this programatically in the margins with all of the optional arguments that I want.

### The Ask

- If there is a specific tool I should use to achieve the goals for my specific case, please feel free to comment on it and/or include it in an answer to the general case.  However, please prefer answering the general question.

Comment: you used verbatim in your first example which completely changes the question as nesting verbatim only  possible in very limited ways. it is hard to imgine you need verbatim for a recipe book though, you are not cooking tex source code???

Comment: your example doesn't print anything. It errors as you can't hide verbatim like this inside another environment.

Comment: `~\\ ` is a very weird construct, probably just use `\par`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ha, its not a coding cookbook! If I wrote that, it would be nothing but a recipe for disaster! I just grabbed verbatim as it was the first default environment that came to mind.  I should fix that so it un-breaks the curly braces.

Comment: you should decide _first_  if verbatim is a requirement. It would require different definition forms and limit the ways it can be used.

Comment: Already updated.  The choice of environment for the example was arbitrary.  Now I'm using `center`.

Comment: Now that verbatim is gone, your MWE compiles. However, it's not clear what output you actually want (to me at least).

Comment: Apologies to all for poorly articulating what I want.  It's a challenge to do without knowing how to make the MWE to demonstrate it.  @DavidCarlisle 's answer seems to have gotten the gist.  If you have recommendations to reformat the question, please let me know so I can help others who land on this.

Answer (score 5):

It really is not very clear what input forms you want or what output they should generate, but here is an environment that takes one optional argument which is a comma separated list of key/value pairs.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\bool_new:N\l_bool_alice
\bool_new:N\l_bool_bob
\keys_define:nn{abc}{
alice.bool_set:N =\l_bool_alice,
bob.bool_set:N = \l_bool_bob,
vegan.tl_set:N= \l_vegan_tl
}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{testenv}{O{}}
    {
   \keys_set:nn {abc}{#1}
        \begin{center}
        \bool_if:NT\l_bool_alice {I ~want ~to ~talk ~about ~Alice.}\par
        \bool_if:NT\l_bool_bob {I ~want ~to ~talk ~about ~Bob.}\par
    }
    {
        \tl_if_empty:NF\l_vegan_tl{\marginpar{\bfseries\l_vegan_tl}}
        \end{center}
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    
\begin{testenv}[alice]
  aaa
\end{testenv}

\bigskip\hrule\bigskip

\begin{testenv}[alice,bob,vegan=wibble]
  bbb
\end{testenv}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the excellent starting point, David.  This is my first time diving into `expl3`, so I'm going to take things slow and experiment a bit until I figure it out.  A few clarifying questions: 1) `\keys_define:nn{abc}` and friends appear to call a module called `abc` if I'm reading the right docs, but this is not the `abc` music package, correct? 2) In `\bool_if:NT\l_bool_alice {I ~want ~to ~talk ~about ~Alice.}\par` is the spacing deliberate to fit with the `\ExplSyntaxOn`?

Comment: I could have used the classic `keyval` package (as used by `\incudegraphics`)  (very reliable author) but as there are literally millions of examples of that on the web, I used the modern way that is built in to recent formats. Yes white space is ignored in `\ExplSyntaxOn` so `~` makes a space (a real space, not a non-breaking space as `~` makes in the main document)  `abc`  is just a random string here, `WesH` might have been a better string for the context @WesH

Comment: `udefined` or `undefined`? It compiles the same either way, but I've never seen `udefined`.

Comment: This works better when I replace `\udefined` with `\empty`.  While in your example, the lack of `vegan=wibble` does not show up in the first, a placeholder still exists in the document.  You can confirm this by replacing the definition conditional with: `\ifx\l_vegan_tl\udefined\else\marginpar{test=\bfseries\l_vegan_tl}\fi`

Comment: @WesH it was a typo but there is no signifcance to either name but as you say, it should be \empty or better use `\tl_if_empty:NF` rather than `\ifx` (I'll fix)

Comment: @WesH fixed....