# Use of keys_define

Tags: l3keys

I have encountered the following.  What are keys about and how are they to be used, for what purpsose.  Could I have some examples ?

```
\keys_define:nn { feuds_teorema_keys }
  {
    name .tl_set:N = \feuds_teorema_name_tl,
    label .tl_set:N = \feuds_teorema_label_tl,
    shared .tl_set:N = \feuds_teorema_shared_tl,
    parent .tl_set:N = \feuds_teorema_parent_tl,
    pigment .tl_set:N = \feuds_teorema_pigment_tl,
  }
```

Comment: keys allow syntax such as `\includegraphics[width=3cm, clip=false]{somefile}` with the values (for width and clip here) being saved as macros and passed to the implementation of the main macro (`\includegraphics` here). `\includegraphics` uses an older key system (`keyval` package) but idea is basically the same.

Comment: Hi, if you don't have a specific problem, I recommend reading the [interface3](https://mirror.funkfreundelandshut.de/latex/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf) doc, p. 233 ff. If you have a particular use case, post a MWE and tell us what you want to achieve ;)

Comment: I am trying to understand the code.  Is it correct to say that when the key `name` is used, its value is assigned to the token list variable `\feuds_teorema_name_tl` ?

Comment: Does one require the last comma in `\feuds_teorema_pigment_tl,` ?

Comment: When the key `name=Jane` is used, the value `Jane` is assigned to the token list. The last comma is not necessary, but better an extra comma than a missing one

Comment: Meaning that `width` and `clip` would then correspond to `name` and `label` in the aforementioned example ?

Comment: But that's all explained in the docs with many understandable examples. And yes to your last question, in this case `width` is similar used as `name`.

Comment: Will have a look and report back.

Comment: @Veak yes, but the documentation has examples and there are thousands of key val examples on this site (and a few examples of `\keys_define:nn { `  as well) if you don't have an actual question and just look for examples, a simple search would answer this.

Comment: for example this answer of mine https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/669182/1090 (we could close this as duplicate?)

Comment: What would `\feuds_teorema_name_tl` be ? When a user passes the value, would the value exist in `\feuds_teorema_name_tl`.  Looks as if the name value would be assigned to `\feuds_teorema_name_tl`.

Comment: As mentioned in a comment on your previous question, your module name is not valid. (https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64492157#64492157)

Comment: @Veak `_tl` is a token list i.e. a variable which can hold a list of zero or more tokens.

Comment: just copying a random fragment of code and asking what it does out of context is a strange way of learning a  language.  but `name .tl_set:N = \feuds_teorema_name_tl,`  means that `name=wibble` is syntactic sugar for a user command that does `\def\feuds_teorema_name_tl{wibble}`  that's all it does, what happens then depends how you use `\feuds_teorema_name_tl`

Comment: I think this question creates more problems than it cant solve.